# How do I load a .csv file with strings and floats in python?

Tags: python, string, numpy, csv

I am trying to load a .csv file that contains 2 columns. The first column has floats and the second column has strings that correspond to each number in the 1st column.

I tried to load them in with `file = np.genfromtxt('tester.csv',delimiter=',', skip_header=1)` but only the floats loaded. The texts all appeared as `nan` in the array. What is the best way to load a .csv file into a 2d array with a column of floats and a column of strings?

The first few lines of the .csv file will look something like this

```
m/z,     Lipid ID
885.5,   PI 18:0_20:4 
857.5,   PI 16:0_20:4
834.5,   PS 18:0_22:6
810.5,   PS 18:0_20:4
790.5,   PE 18:0_22:6
```

Comment: Will you please show a few lines of your CSV file?

Comment: Sorry for that. Just added them!

Comment: Thank you. Are the large gaps between columns several space (` `) characters in a row or tabs (`\t`)?

Comment: Oh so I just did that to make it easy to look. Each number and lipid name will be in a cell

Comment: What will the separator be? `,`?

Comment: Yes, I assume `,`  is the delimiter as it is a .csv file.

Comment: Can you use pandas? Or do you prefer to use numpy?

Comment: I think using pandas as others replied would be fine :) But I would be interested in doing it with numpy if there is a way

Comment: Okay, I found a way using pure numpy. I'll submit an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas` to load your csv file, and then convert it to `numpy` array using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tester.csv')
df_to_array = np.array(df)
```

Your csv will be stored in df_to_array as a numpy array.

Comment: Or instead of `np.array(df)`: `df.to_numpy()`

Comment: Both are possible :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid the nans, you need to tell `genfromtxt` the dtypes of the columns, because, by default, it tries to make everything a float.

```
dtypes = ['float', 'object']
csv = np.array(np.genfromtxt('tester.csv',delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=dtypes).tolist())
```

Output:

```
>>> csv
array([[885.5, b'PI 18:0_20:4'],
       [857.5, b'PI 16:0_20:4'],
       [834.5, b'PS 18:0_22:6'],
       [810.5, b'PS 18:0_20:4'],
       [790.5, b'PE 18:0_22:6']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: That "oddlly" way is called a `structured array`.  The result is a 1d array with 2 fields, one for each column, each with its own dtype.  That's rather like the `pandas` dataframe with different dtypes for each column (Series).

Comment: Okay, thank you @hpaulj. Do you know of a better way to deal with that than using `unpack=True` and transposing?

Comment: Depends on the desired result.  Is a 2d object dtype array better?  `np.array(data.tolist(), dtype=object)` is another option.

Comment: Oh yeah, that actually worked! Interesting. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you use `numpy`, you can install `pandas` to load your csv file:

```
# Python env: pip install pandas
# Anaconda env: conda install pandas
df = pd.read_csv('tester.csv', sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [228]: txt="""m/z,     Lipid ID
     ...: 885.5,   PI 18:0_20:4 
     ...: 857.5,   PI 16:0_20:4
     ...: 834.5,   PS 18:0_22:6
     ...: 810.5,   PS 18:0_20:4
     ...: 790.5,   PE 18:0_22:6
     ...: """
```

`genfromtxt` has a lot of possible parameters.  It's not as fast as the `pandas` equivalent, but still quite flixible.

```
In [229]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=None, encoding=None, 
     names=True, autostrip=True)
In [230]: data
Out[230]: 
array([(885.5, 'PI 18:0_20:4'), (857.5, 'PI 16:0_20:4'),
       (834.5, 'PS 18:0_22:6'), (810.5, 'PS 18:0_20:4'),
       (790.5, 'PE 18:0_22:6')],
      dtype=[('mz', '<f8'), ('Lipid_ID', '<U12')])
```

This is a structured array, with 2 fields.  Because of the `names` parameter, field names are taken from the file header line.  With `dtype=None`, it deduces a dtype for each column, in this case float and string.  Fields are accessed by name:

```
In [231]: data['Lipid_ID']
Out[231]: 
array(['PI 18:0_20:4', 'PI 16:0_20:4', 'PS 18:0_22:6', 'PS 18:0_20:4',
       'PE 18:0_22:6'], dtype='<U12')
In [232]: data['mz']
Out[232]: array([885.5, 857.5, 834.5, 810.5, 790.5])
```

To make a 2d array we have to cast it to object dtype, allowing a mix of numbers and strings.

```
In [233]: np.array(data.tolist(), object)
Out[233]: 
array([[885.5, 'PI 18:0_20:4'],
       [857.5, 'PI 16:0_20:4'],
       [834.5, 'PS 18:0_22:6'],
       [810.5, 'PS 18:0_20:4'],
       [790.5, 'PE 18:0_22:6']], dtype=object)
```

The structured arrays can be loaded into a dataframe, with a result similar to what a pandas read would produce:

```
In [235]: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[235]: 
      mz      Lipid_ID
0  885.5  PI 18:0_20:4
1  857.5  PI 16:0_20:4
2  834.5  PS 18:0_22:6
3  810.5  PS 18:0_20:4
4  790.5  PE 18:0_22:6
```

Dataframe `to_records` produces a structured array, much like what we started with.

```
In [238]: _235.to_records(index=False)
Out[238]: 
rec.array([(885.5, 'PI 18:0_20:4'), (857.5, 'PI 16:0_20:4'),
           (834.5, 'PS 18:0_22:6'), (810.5, 'PS 18:0_20:4'),
           (790.5, 'PE 18:0_22:6')],
          dtype=[('mz', '<f8'), ('Lipid_ID', 'O')])
```